# Sapper reloading [slug] page no html, only json on page

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

Newbie to Sapper and Svelte, have used other frameworks.

I've created an author site in sapper that lists author's books on the main page, and then a book-specific page linked from the book items - the book page is in `books/[slug].svelte` (and `books/[slug].js` for the server side.)

Going to the book page from the link (located in another component) renders perfectly - no issues.

If I reload, or type in the book url directly, there's no html: the page shows the json for the book item.  The inspector shows only a `pre` tag filled with the json.

The site is patterned pretty much after the demo site created from the degit rollup template (and modified from that.)

Any idea what's happening, here?  What am I missing, I wonder?

Thoughts appreciated.  I can provide more details and a github repo, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have overlapping routes -- your API route and your page are both located at /books/slug-goes-here. When you navigate client-side, Sapper swaps in the new Svelte component and does not request anything from the server. When you go there directly, the browser requests /books/slug-goes-here and receives the JSON from your API.

To fix this, you should rename your server route to `[slug].json.js` and fetch /books/slug-goes-here.json in your component. This way, you have two different routes: /books/slug-goes-here returns the HTML page and /books/slug-goes-here.json returns the JSON data for that page.

```
<!-- [slug].svelte -->
<script context="module">
    export async function preload({ params }) {
        // this is the component located at books/[slug]
        // it requests books/[slug].json to get its data
        const res = await this.fetch(`books/${params.slug}.json`);
        const data = await res.json();

        // etc
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Woohoo!!  That did it.  I saw that naming in the example and it didn't quite click.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question: Let's say I want a server .js file parallel to the root `/src/routes/index.svelte` file.  Presumably, that would be named `/src/routes/index.json.js`, right?  I try that, but I don't seem to be able to reference it from the `index.svelte` file - I've tried `fetch('json'), fetch('/json'), fetch('json.js')` etc., but it always returns a '404'. Is there a way to do that?  My current solution was to move the .js file down into the 'books' folder, and then I can reference it as `books.json`.  That works, but doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: Whoop - never mind.  I got it: `fetch('index.json')`.  Onward.